# Angularjs giving exception in IE

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, svg

I am creating a project using angularjs. In my project i have implemented SVG2Bitmap, which is working fine in all browsers except in IE.In the offical documention
https://github.com/Kaiido/SVG2Bitmap
says this is supported in IE.
Here is my code:

```
SVG2Bitmap(this, function(canvas, dataURL) {
  console.log("SVG2Bitmap")
  canvas.id = "canvas_" + id;
  canvasArr.push(canvas)
  parent.replaceChild(canvas, thisData);
  var image1, image2, image3,image4,image5 = null;



  var p2 =  new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

    html2canvas(html, {
      onrendered: function(canvas) {
        image1 = canvas.toDataURL();
        resolve(image1)
      }
    });
  });
})

object DOMException{ABORT_ERR: 20, code: 12, DATA_CLONE_ERR: 25, DOMSTRING_SIZE_ERR: 2, HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: 3, INDEX_SIZE_ERR: 1, INUSE_ATTRIBUTE_ERR: 10, INVALID_ACCESS_ERR: 15, INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: 5, INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR: 13, INVALID_NODE_TYPE_ERR: 24, INVALID_STATE_ERR: 11, message: "SyntaxError", name: "SyntaxError", NAMESPACE_ERR: 14, NETWORK_ERR: 19, NO_DATA_ALLOWED_ERR: 6, NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR: 7, NOT_FOUND_ERR: 8, NOT_SUPPORTED_ERR: 9, PARSE_ERR: 81
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: object DOMException{ABORT_ERR: 20, code: 12, DATA_CLONE_ERR: 25, DOMSTRING_SIZE_ERR: 2, HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: 3, INDEX_SIZE_ERR: 1, INUSE_ATTRIBUTE_ERR: 10, INVALID_ACCESS_ERR: 15, INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: 5, INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR: 13, INVALID_NODE_TYPE_ERR: 24, INVALID_STATE_ERR: 11, message: "SyntaxError", name: "SyntaxError", NAMESPACE_ERR: 14, NETWORK_ERR: 19, NO_DATA_ALLOWED_ERR: 6, NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR: 7, NOT_FOUND_ERR: 8, NOT_SUPPORTED_ERR: 9, PARSE_ERR: 81 .

Comment: Promise is [not supported in IE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#Browser_compatibility). Use the AngularJS [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) service instead.

Comment: @ccprog The error doesn't mention `Promise` probably not even getting to that part of the code yet or it's been polyfilled.

Comment: @angular You could update your question with the error. It would probably be easier to read. At what line in the code does this error occur? I have not worked with IE for a while but that dump doesn't look like anything useful, is that what the console shows you?

Comment: The one thing the error states is that it is a DOMException SyntaxError. `parent.replaceChild(canvas, thisData);` looks suspicious. Is `thisData` really a valid DOM node?